# If statement in series of tasks?

Tags: gulp

I have checked out gulpif and various other posts, but they only state how to do this inside a task.

I want to be able to have an if statement to decide which task in a series to run, something like:

```
gulp.task('build',
gulp.series(task1, task2, task3, if(true){task 4} else {task5}));
```

Comment: check gulp-if module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if

Comment: As stated in the question, I have already checked that out - it doesnt do what I need it to do.

Comment: soz, readed so fast. Is there are reason you're using gulp.series() instead of passing dependency tasks as array?

Comment: previously set up script I dont want to mess with

Comment: Because, you could set up a dependency array depending on conditions, and then pass it to gulp.task:  var deps = condition ? ['task1' ,'task3'] : ['task1' , 'task2', 'task4']; gulp.task('build' , deps);

Comment: @Sergeon He's using gulp 4 not gulp 3 so that won't work (although a gulp 4 solution would be similar)

Comment: Could you show me a gulp 4 implementation of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
gulp.series(task1, task2, task3, condition ? task4 : task5);
```